# Get the regToken from a GSResponse

Tags: android, single-sign-on, gigya

The situation is as following:

I send a login request using the method `showLoginUI` and then, after selecting a provider (Twitter, g+, etc.) the app goes to the `onError` callback of my `GSLoginUIListener` with the error "Account pending registration". Until that point, everything is fine. The problem is when I try to create another `GSRequest` with the method "accounts.setAccountInfo" like in the following code:

```
GSRequest setAccountInfoRequest = new GSRequest(getString(R.string.gigya_api_key),"accounts.setAccountInfo");
```

As parameter, I believe I have to add the `regToken` but where can I get it? In the iOS SDK, there is an Error object (that you get from the `GSResponse` that allows you to get it like this:

```
token = error.userInfo["regToken"]
```

But there is nothing like that on the Android SDK, from the `GSResponse` I just can get the error code, error message and error details. So, in short, how can I get the `regToken` that I need for my request? In [the documentation](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.socialLogin+REST) does not go into the details of the actual implementation and I have not seen any examples.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the iOS and .NET SDKs, the Android SDK does not have a publicly expose or documented `GSRequest` class, so invoking a request the way you are doing it is not advisable.

Instead, you should use [`GSAPI.sendRequest`](http://wikifiles.gigya.com/SDKs/Android/doc/com/gigya/socialize/android/GSAPI.html#sendRequest-java.lang.String-com.gigya.socialize.GSObject-boolean-com.gigya.socialize.GSResponseListener-java.lang.Object-) with a `GSResponseListener`.  The GSResponseListener will have a response object with the method `getData` which can be invoked to get a dictionary object of all the parameters returned from the request.

An example of how this can be done is provided in our [Gigya CS Android demo](https://github.com/Gigya-ClientServices/Gigya-Android-Demos) hosted on GitHub and can be examined in the file [SessionInfoFragment.java@121-191](https://github.com/Gigya-ClientServices/Gigya-Android-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/gigyaandroiddemos/gigya/com/GigyaAndroidDemos/SessionInfoFragment.java#L121-L191).

```
public void refreshView() {
    GSAPI gigya = GSAPI.getInstance();
    final TextView statusText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.status_value);
    final TextView nameText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_value);
    final TextView emailText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email_value);
    final ImageView avatarView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);

    if (gigya.getSession() != null){
        if (gigya.getSession().isValid()) {
            MainActivity parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            GSObject user = parent.getUser();

            // Retrieve the user if it's not set. (Reloaded app with active session)
            if (user == null) {
                GSResponseListener resListener = new GSResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGSResponse(String method, GSResponse response, Object context) {
                        try {
                            if (response.getErrorCode()==0) { // SUCCESS! response status = OK
                                MainActivity parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                                Log.w("Gigya-Android-Demos", "Successfully set user");
                                parent.setUser(response.getData());
                                setLoggedIn(statusText, nameText, emailText, avatarView, response.getData());
                            } else {  // Error
                                Log.w("Gigya-Android-Demos", "GSResponse: 'getAccountInfo' returned an error");
                                Log.w("Gigya-Android-Demos", response.getErrorMessage());
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {  ex.printStackTrace();  }
                    }
                };
                GSAPI.getInstance()
                        .sendRequest("accounts.getAccountInfo", null, resListener, null );
            } else {
                // Grab the user data
                setLoggedIn(statusText, nameText, emailText, avatarView, user);
            }

        } else {
            setLoggedOut(statusText, nameText, emailText, avatarView);
        }
    } else {
        setLoggedOut(statusText, nameText, emailText, avatarView);
    }
}

public void setLoggedOut(TextView status, TextView name, TextView email, ImageView avatar) {
    status.setText(getString(R.string.logged_out));
    name.setText(getString(R.string.null_value));
    email.setText(getString(R.string.null_value));
    setUnknownAvatar(avatar);
}

public void setLoggedIn(TextView status, TextView name, TextView emailView, ImageView avatar, GSObject user) {
    status.setText(getString(R.string.logged_in));
    try {
        GSObject profile = user.getObject("profile");
        String first = profile.getString("firstName");
        String last = profile.getString("lastName");
        String email = profile.getString("email");
        if (profile.containsKey("photoURL")) {
            setAvatar(avatar,profile.getString("photoURL"));
        } else {
            setUnknownAvatar(avatar);
        }
        name.setText(first + " " + last);
        emailView.setText(email);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.w("Gigya-Android-Demos", "Something went horribly wrong with the user!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You should notice the use of `getData()` and `GSObject` classes throughout the example provided.  Using this method of making a request, you should be able to examine the response data including the `regToken`.